# Rails way to query on many-to-many privileges

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got an application with users and stores, and a many-to-many association through a users_stores table.  A manager for one of the stores is logged in, and I need to show them a user list for the users from their stores.

I'm wondering if there is a Rails way to do this in Active Record?

This is relatively easy to query with a join e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM users, users_stores
INNER JOIN ON users.id = user_stores.user_id
WHERE store_id IN [1,2]
```

I think I know how to write that with active record, but it would have duplicate users if the manager and the user are both associated to the same two stores.  I could also write it with a subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users_stores
        WHERE user.id = users_stores.user_id
        AND store_id IN [1,2] ) > 0
```

But I've got no idea how to write that one in active record.

Is there a way to do the second query with active record, or should I just run the first query, and then locally process the results to remove duplicates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: I'd do it locally.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :stores do
    # eager load appropriately or kill your db
    def users
      @users ||= inject([]){|users, store| users.concat store.users}.uniq
    end
  end
end
```

Use like this:

```
@user.stores.users
```

*Edit*: using `ActiveRelation`, one more db hit. Usage is the same but lets you do `ActiveRelation` stuff like `@user.stores.users.where(:pants => 'fancy')`.

```
class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
  class << self
    def users
      User.where(:id => includes(:users).map{|store| store.users.map(&:id)})
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Wow! I've done it and it works - I hadn't realised blocks can be supplied to has_many.  Thanks very much

Comment: You can also add this method into the `Store` class, but I put it here because it doesn't return an `ActiveRelation` object like you'd normally expect. In other words: kinda hacky.

Answer (score 0):

In rails you need to define the relationships between tables in the model. You can define a n..n relationship using `has_and_belongs_to_many` or `has_many` with the `:through` option.

You can read more about that in the documentation of the associations:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

In your case it would probably be like this:

`User` Model:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :stores
```

`Store` Model:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :users
```

When you have done that you can simply `find` an object and call the association like this:

```
@user=User.find(params[:id])
@user.stores # Will return the associated stores
```

Or the other way round:

```
@store=Store.find(params[:id)
@store.users # Will return the associated users
```

Comment: I understand that, but I'm trying to potentially get the set of users for a set of stores - effectively @store_array.users would be wonderful!

Answer (score 0):

Active Record provides many to many relationship:

User Model

```
has_many :user_stores
has_many :stores :through => user_stores
```

Store Model

```
has_many :user_stores
has_many :users :through => user_stores
```

then you could get all stores of a user by calling:
    `@user.stores` 
or 
    `@store.users`